# Next js with i18next module not found issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-i18next

## I have a nextjs type script application using i18next.

> my i18n file is in typescript

the build of the project was successfull but when i had to run it says it cannot load the i18n module which is in typescript what is the work around this

#### my i18n.tsx

```
import NextI18Next from 'next-i18next'

const NextI18NextInstance = new NextI18Next({
  defaultLanguage: 'en',
  otherLanguages: ['ar'],
  detection: {
    lookupCookie: 'next-i18next',
    order: ['cookie', 'querystring', 'localStorage', 'path', 'subdomain'],
    caches: ['cookie'],
  }
})


module.exports =  NextI18NextInstance

export const {
  appWithTranslation,
  withTranslation,
  i18n
} = NextI18NextInstance
```

my pakage.json scripts

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node --project tsconfig.server.json server/index.ts",
    "build:server": "tsc --project tsconfig.server.json",
    "build:next": "next build",
    "build": "npm run build:next && npm run build:server",
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=production node dist/index.js"
  }
```

#### the build dist/index.js file

```
"use strict";
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
var __generator = (this && this.__generator) || function (thisArg, body) {
    var _ = { label: 0, sent: function() { if (t[0] & 1) throw t[1]; return t[1]; }, trys: [], ops: [] }, f, y, t, g;
    return g = { next: verb(0), "throw": verb(1), "return": verb(2) }, typeof Symbol === "function" && (g[Symbol.iterator] = function() { return this; }), g;
    function verb(n) { return function (v) { return step([n, v]); }; }
    function step(op) {
        if (f) throw new TypeError("Generator is already executing.");
        while (_) try {
            if (f = 1, y && (t = op[0] & 2 ? y["return"] : op[0] ? y["throw"] || ((t = y["return"]) && t.call(y), 0) : y.next) && !(t = t.call(y, op[1])).done) return t;
            if (y = 0, t) op = [op[0] & 2, t.value];
            switch (op[0]) {
                case 0: case 1: t = op; break;
                case 4: _.label++; return { value: op[1], done: false };
                case 5: _.label++; y = op[1]; op = [0]; continue;
                case 7: op = _.ops.pop(); _.trys.pop(); continue;
                default:
                    if (!(t = _.trys, t = t.length > 0 && t[t.length - 1]) && (op[0] === 6 || op[0] === 2)) { _ = 0; continue; }
                    if (op[0] === 3 && (!t || (op[1] > t[0] && op[1] < t[3]))) { _.label = op[1]; break; }
                    if (op[0] === 6 && _.label < t[1]) { _.label = t[1]; t = op; break; }
                    if (t && _.label < t[2]) { _.label = t[2]; _.ops.push(op); break; }
                    if (t[2]) _.ops.pop();
                    _.trys.pop(); continue;
            }
            op = body.call(thisArg, _);
        } catch (e) { op = [6, e]; y = 0; } finally { f = t = 0; }
        if (op[0] & 5) throw op[1]; return { value: op[0] ? op[1] : void 0, done: true };
    }
};
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var express_1 = __importDefault(require("express"));
var next_1 = __importDefault(require("next"));
var nextI18NextMiddleware = require('next-i18next/middleware').default;
var nextI18next = require('../i18n');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var app = next_1.default({ dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' });
var handle = app.getRequestHandler();
(function () { return __awaiter(void 0, void 0, void 0, function () {
    var server;
    return __generator(this, function (_a) {
        switch (_a.label) {
            case 0: return [4 /*yield*/, app.prepare()];
            case 1:
                _a.sent();
                server = express_1.default();
                return [4 /*yield*/, nextI18next.initPromise];
            case 2:
                _a.sent();
                server.use(nextI18NextMiddleware(nextI18next));
                server.get('*', function (req, res) { return handle(req, res); });
                return [4 /*yield*/, server.listen(port)];
            case 3:
                _a.sent();
                console.log("> Ready on http://localhost:" + port); // eslint-disable-line no-console
                return [2 /*return*/];
        }
    });
}); })();
```

I am unable to run the server as it is saying the file i18n not found ,what should be the solution to this any help would be great.

Comment: Did you made all of next-i18next steps? server & client?

Comment: Yes , instead of js I used type script ,found a temporary workaround created another i18n.js file .but what would be the exact work around this ?